# Having problems with Python, OpenSCAD and solidpython, when trying to use special characters, as output

Tags: python, character-encoding, char, openscad

so im writing a program to automate making items with names on them, and im encountering a problem when trying to render the models with **special characters **ž đ š ć č****, where it cant translate them i guess and it just ends up crashing. ill post the code here and explain a bit within it.

```
This is part of the program, where the issue is 

import pandas as pd
from solid import *
import subprocess
import time

if name == ‘main’:
# Read the Excel file

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\data.xlsx" ,sheet_name='Sheet1')
#print(df.iterrows)
num_rows = len(df)
#print(df)
#print(df.shape)
# Iterate through each row of the Excel sheet
for index, row in df.iterrows():
# Read values from the first row and first three columns
    annotation1 = row.iloc[2] #1st phone number
    annotation2 = row.iloc[0] #Name
    annotation3 = row.iloc[3] #2nd phone number
    annotation4 = row.iloc[1] #Surname
    full_name = f"{annotation2} {annotation4}"
    **#full_name = str(annotation2)+" "+str(annotation4)**
    #print(full_name)
  
    #print(annotation1,annotation2,annotation3,annotation4)
    # Generate the assembly
    a = assembly(annotation1,str(full_name), annotation3)
  
    # Output the SCAD file with dynamic name based on annotation1
    scad_file = f"export_{annotation2}.scad"
    scad_file_location = f"C:\\Users\\Miki\\Desktop\\SCADfiles"
    scad_render_to_file(a, scad_file, include_orig_code=False)

   

    ######### Problem ko hočem renderat file ne gre, ker ima "full_name" presledek in ga unicoda ne sprejme. help
    #Problem when i want to render the file, it doesnt let me since the "full name" has restricted character "\t" and doesnt work then i guess xD

    # Run OpenSCAD to export the STL file
   ** stl_file = f"{annotation2}.stl"
    command = f"openscad -o C:\\Users\\Miki\\Desktop\\STLfiles\\{stl_file} C:\\Users\\Miki\\Desktop\\SCADfiles\\{scad_file}"
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
    time.sleep(50)
    print(full_name, "je opravljen.")***
This here is the error given back, as you can see it crashes at scad_render_to_file where var a has a var within itself “full_name” that contains a special char.
```

This here is the error given back, as you can see it crashes at scad_render_to_file where var a has a var within itself “full_name” that contains a special char.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “c:\Users\Miki\Desktop\Model_cut_v3.py”, line 87, in
scad_render_to_file(a, scad_file, include_orig_code=False)
File “C:\Users\Miki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\solid\solidpython.py”, line 518, in scad_render_to_file
return _write_code_to_file(rendered_string, filepath, out_dir, include_orig_code)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File “C:\Users\Miki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\solid\solidpython.py”, line 562, in _write_code_to_file
out_path.write_text(rendered_string)
File “C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py”, line 1048, in write_text
return f.write(data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File “C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py”, line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: ‘charmap’ codec can’t encode character ‘\u010d’ in position 555: character maps to
```

So i was wondering, how i can fix this. Is there maybe a way to decode it within OpenSCAD?, though i dont know if thats possible.

Well if anyone has any ideas how to fix this, i would really appriciate it.

I tried encoing it in to ascii, and it resulted in well ascii values for each letter, which is not what i want. I also tried encoing it with utf-8, and had again an not satisfying result.
if anyone can help, thanks

Comment: Something is trying to use code page 1252, which doesn't contain those characters.  I don't know how the encoding is selected.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean how the encoding i selected. this is just a project, and basicly my first time programming. the thing is, the string that is given to the "scad_render_to_file" function needs to be exact as it will copy the value and literly paste it in to OpenSCAD, and will linear extrude that text. the thing is i dont know how this encoding works, but i just need it to work...

Comment: All characters that are written to a file are written as bytes.  The conversion between characters and bytes is determined by the encoding.  The code page 1252 is one such encoding, but there are lots of characters it can't handle.  As I said I don't know how that encoding is being selected, it's not being done by the code you posted.  It must be a default of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

```py
scad_file_location = f"C:\\Users\\Miki\\Desktop\\SCADfiles\\export_{annotation2}.scad"
with open(scad_file_location, "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(scad_render(model))
```